# Progress bar colour not updating after being set

Tags: c#, winforms, pinvoke

I have been trying to set the colour of the standard WinForms progress bars but also retain the Vista+ theming (and animation).

I have come across this:

```
private static uint PBM_SETSTATE = 0x410;
public enum State { Normal = 1, Error = 2, Warning = 3 };

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    public static void SetState(ProgressBar progressBar, int nState)
    {
        SendMessage(progressBar.Handle, PBM_SETSTATE, (IntPtr)nState, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

This seems to work, but not consistently. Sometimes the progress bar doesn't appear to have changed colour, but when the window is slightly resized or moved off screen and back it changes colour.

[image]

To add a bit more background to this question i have a task which is executing a long running process and i am sending the progress bar updates via a synchronization context.

```
m_oSynchronizationContext.Send(o => { oAction(); }, null);
```

I presume this is a refresh issue, i have tried calling Refresh() on the progress bar but it has made no difference.

[Link to reproduction code](http://pastebin.com/1eafJQuW)

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd try to help, but am put off by having to look up magic constants. An MCVE would also help.

Comment: Off site links are no good. Please make a real mcve and post here.